# Seperate accents from their letters

Tags: python, unicode

I'm looking for a function that will take a compound letter and split it as if you had to type it on a US-INTL keyboard, like so:

```
'ȯ' becomes ".o"
'â' becomes "^a"
'ë' becomes "\"e"
'è' becomes "`e"
'é' becomes "'e"
'ñ' becomes "~n"
'ç' becomes ",c"
```

etc.

But when searching for this issue I can only find functions to remove accents entirely, which is not what I want.

Here's what I want to accomplish:

Expand this string:

`ër íí àha lá eïsch`

into this string:

`` "er 'i'i `aha l'a e"isch ``

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking for, but converting to Unicode's decomposed normal form using unicodedata.normalize() might be a step in the right direction. Given the extreme variability in keyboard layouts, I doubt that there is a packaged one-step solution available.

Comment: @TurePålsson I added the spec that it should follow on a US-INTL keyboard. I tried `unicodedata.normalize('NFD',"Ä")` which returned the A (good) with a weird specific diacritic character (bad). I guess I could find and replace those diacritics but I think I'll wait for a better solution. I'd also need to reverse the pairs as they are inserted in the wrong order by normalize().

Comment: I doubt there will be a better solution than Unicode normalisation plus replacement (you'll have to also swap places, because combining diacritics go after the base character). Your requirements are specific and arbitrary, that's why you'll probably have to create your own mapping table. If you think combining diacritcs are weird, you're in for surprises if you dig further into Unicode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly use a dictionary to match the characters with their replacements and then iterate over the string to do the actual replacement.

```
word_rep = dict(zip(['ȯ','â','ë','è','é','ñ','ç'] 
['.o','^a','\"e','`e','\'e','~n',',c']))
mystr = 'ër íí àha lá eïsch'
for key,value in word_rep.items():
    mystr = mystr.replace(key,value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below uses Unicode decomposition to separate combining marks from latin letters, a regular expression to swap the combining character and its letter, then a translation table to convert the combining mark to the key used on the international keyboard:

```
import unicodedata as ud
import re

replacements = {'\N{COMBINING DOT ABOVE}':'.',
                '\N{COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT}':'^',
                '\N{COMBINING DIAERESIS}':'"',
                '\N{COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT}':'`',
                '\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}':"'",
                '\N{COMBINING TILDE}':'~',
                '\N{COMBINING CEDILLA}':','}

combining = ''.join(replacements.keys())
typing = ''.join(replacements.values())

translation = str.maketrans(combining,typing)

s = 'ër íí àha lá eïsch'
s = ud.normalize('NFD',s)
s = re.sub(rf'([aeiounc])([{combining}])',r'\2\1',s)
s = s.translate(translation)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
"er 'i'i `aha l'a e"isch
```